# python set union operation is not behaving well with named tuples

Tags: python, set, namedtuple, python-collections

I want to create a set of `namedtuple` in python, with the ability to add elements dynamically using the union operation.

The following code snippet creates a `set` of `namedtuple`, which is behaving nicely.

```
from collections import namedtuple

B = namedtuple('B', 'name x')

b1 = B('b1',90)
b2 = B('b2',92)
s = set([b1,b2])
print(s)
```

which prints

```
{B(name='b1', x=90), B(name='b2', x=92)}
```

Now if I create another `namedtuple` and add it to my `set` with the `union` operations it is not behaving as expected.

```
b3 = B('b3',93)
s = s.union(b3)
print(s)
```

The code snippet prints the following output.

```
{93, B(name='b1', x=90), B(name='b2', x=92), 'b3'}
```

The expected output should be:

```
{B(name='b1', x=90), B(name='b2', x=92), B(name='b3', x=93)}
```

Am I mis-understanding the API?
Both python2 and 3 are showing the same behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`union` expects a set (or a list or another iterable), but you pass a named tuple, which is an iterable by itself, but it provides values, so you merge the set with the values. Try this:

```
s = s.union({b3})
```

Answer (score 5):

A `namedtuple` instance is an iterable of items. `set.union` simply merges the current set with the items in the `namedtuple`.

However, what you want is put the `namedtuple` in another container/iterable, so the merge is done with the item (the `namedtuple`) contained in the new parent iterable:

```
s.union((b3,))
```

It becomes more obvious if you actually think of the operator equivalent:

```
s = s | set(b3) # set(b3) -> {93, 'b3'}
```

As compared to what we actually want:

```
s = s | {b3}
```

The *union* is performed with the outer iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Since `b3` is iterable, `union` works on its elements rather than on the tuple itself. Replace that with:

```
s = s.union([b3])
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on [`set.union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) actually explains this:

> `union(*others)`
>
> Return a new set with elements from the set and all others.

So it will create a new set including all elements from the `others`:

```
>>> set(b3)  # these are the unique elements in your `b3`
{93, 'b3'}

>>> s.union(b3)   # the union of the unique elements in "s" and "b3"
{B(name='b1', x=90), 93, 'b3', B(name='b2', x=92)}
```

In your case (because you assign it back to `s`) you can simply add the item thus avoiding creating a new set entirely:

```
>>> s.add(b3)
>>> s
{B(name='b1', x=90), B(name='b3', x=93), B(name='b2', x=92)}
```